# Shared code between two different GWT project

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I am Trying to shared code between Two GWT project. But my problem is that once i load one project, Entry point of included project also called. 
 what i have done:
1. MainProjectA (Code of this project want to share)
2. ProjectB (in this project i want code of  MainProjectA).

i include MainProjectA through jar.

Problem i fetch :

when i load ProjectB at that time Entrypoint of MainProjectA also called. i want only method to call which i called from projectB.

Please help me.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GWTModules/article.html

Comment: Thanks @OviFaur. I got solution.

Answer (score 0):

Better thing is to restructure your main project A
You need to create two gwt.xml files in your project.

1. common.gwt.xml

   - contains no enrty point
   - contains source tag for shared codes
2. main.gwt.xml

   - contains your entry point
   - inherits common

Then in your project B, inherit module common

Comment: Thanks @Syam. I was Removing EntryPoint manualy from main.gwt.xml. Your post help me for better solution. thanks again.